# How to use Ajax in Smarty?

Tags: ajax, smarty

This is ajax request

```
<script type="text/javascript">
{literal}
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#S1").change(function()
{

var IDCat=this.value;
alert(IDCat);

$.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: 'product_modify.php',
data: {IDCat:IDCat},
success: function(data)
{
alert(data);
alert("success");
}
});
});
});
{/literal}
</script>
```

And this is php codes

```
 if(isset($_GET['IDCat'])){
     $idc= $_GET['IDCat'];
    echo $idc;
    }
```

there is the problem echo $idc; doesn't work  ? where is the problem  ?

Comment: Only a suggestion: put your JS-code into a seperate file. Your files will be more readable, easier to maintain, in editors will correct syntax highlighting, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var IDCat=this.value;
```

should be

```
var IDCat=$(this).val();
```